# Trying to change team javascript baseball program

Tags: javascript

I am using the `code.org` javascript library. I'm trying to have it so it changes team based on the two selected once 3 outs are reached. I tried to declare `team1` and `team2` and setting them equal to the check box that is selected but that doesnt work correctly.

The team name doesn't change on the label like it does when you first select a team. I'm not quite sure how to do it but the main goal is to get the team name to change when the current team gets 3 outs. There is a label that is being used in the player selection function that displays the 1st team selected.

```
var outs = 0;
var team1 = "";
var team2 = "";
var strikes = 0;
var balls = 0;
var fouls = 0;
var inning = 0;
var hit = 0;
var currentPlayer = team1, team2;

//Player Selection
onEvent("btnStart","click", function() {
  var chkBoxs = ["Yankees", "Boston", "Astros"];
  var selected = [];
  for (var index = 0; selected.length < 2 && index < chkBoxs.length; index++) {
    if (getChecked(chkBoxs[index])) { selected.push(index); }
  }
  setScreen("game");
  if (selected.length == 2) {
    console.log("The Teams are: " + chkBoxs[selected[0]] + " and " + chkBoxs[selected[1]]);
  }
  if (chkBoxs[selected[0]]) {
    setText("lblTeamGame",chkBoxs[selected[0]]);
    team1 = chkBoxs[selected[0]];
    team2 = chkBoxs[selected[1]];
  } else {
    setText("lblTeamGame",chkBoxs[selected[1]]);
  }
});

//Pitching Rules
function Count() {
  if (balls == 4)
  {
    console.log("Walk");
    setText("lblBallCount", 0);
    setText("lblStrikeCount", 0);
    balls = 0;
    strikes = 0;
  }
  if (strikes == 3)
  {
    console.log("Strike Out");
    outs++;
    setText("lblStrikeCount", 0);
    setText("lblOutCount", outs);
    setText("lblBallCount", 0);
    strikes = 0;
    balls = 0;
  }
  if (outs == 3)
  {
    inning++;
    setText("lblInningCount", inning);
    switchPlayer();
  }
  if(hit)
  {
    setText("lblStrikeCount", 0);
    setText("lblBallCount", 0);
    strikes = 0;
    balls = 0;
  }
}
//Switch Teams 
function switchPlayer() {
  if(currentPlayer == team1) {
    currentPlayer = team2;
    showElement("player2_highlight");
    hideElement("player1_highlight");
  } else {
    showElement("player1_highlight");
    hideElement("player2_highlight");
    currentPlayer = 1;
  }
  console.log("current player is: " + currentPlayer);
}
```

Comment: "but that doesnt work correctly" Can you tell us more about the problem please

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work correctly"? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be your problem:

```
function switchPlayer(){
 if(currentPlayer==team1){
     currentPlayer=team2;
     showElement("player2_highlight");
     hideElement("player1_highlight");
 } else {
   showElement("player1_highlight");
   hideElement("player2_highlight");
   currentPlayer=team1; // Specify team1 instead of just 1
 }
 console.log("current player is: "+currentPlayer);
}
```

Also, after switching teams, you need to reset the number of outs.

```
   if(outs==3)
   {
      inning++;
      setText("lblInningCount",inning);
      switchPlayer();
      outs=0;
   }
```